# what happens if buffer's data type mismatches (int * versus unsigned int *) when calling a function?

Tags: c, heap-memory, buffer-overflow

So suppose one has function:

```
int somefunc(int* buf)
```

but we call somefunc by:

```
somefunc(buf2)
```

where `buf2` is heap buffer, allocated by `alloca`, that has data of type `unsigned int` (thus pointer `buf2` is of type `unsigned int*`).

What is the danger of doing this? What would be the problem here? I do think this might have to do with heap(buffer) overflow, but I am not sure what that would be. There may be some other problems with the code, and if so, I do want to know about these problems too.

Example code:

```
void typecastfunc(FILE *p, int *buf, unsigned int index) {
    unsigned int a;
    for (a = 0; a < index; a++) {
        if (fread(&buf[a], sizeof(unsigned int), 1, p) < 1) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void caller(char *filen) {
    FILE *p = fopen(filen, "rb");
    if (!p) {
        return;
    }
    unsigned int index;
    fread(&index, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, p);
    unsigned int *buf = alloca(index * sizeof(unsigned int));
    if (!buf) {
        return;
    }
    typecastfunc(p, buf, index);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    caller(argv[1]);
}
```

The question is being asked, because by randomly fuzzing, I was able to get the signs of overflow, but I do not know how overflow can occur by type mismatch. Other codes seem harmless, so I assume it must be because of type mismatch.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Show us the declarations *as code*.

Comment: You might experience implicit casts or conversions. Implicit usually means "not planned in detail" which often turns into "unwanted". Casting/converting between int and unsigned int "often works", because of same size, same semantic in the range of 0-MAX_INT. But those "harmlessnesses" are assumptions, as soon as any of them is not applicable you will have hard to debug problems. None of them are officially reliable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I now provided an example code.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading data from a binary stream into an array of `int` by chunks of size `sizeof(unsigned int)`.

While it would be better to use the proper type, there is no bad consequences to expect from this particular mistake as the size of `int` is guaranteed  y the standard to be identical to the size of `unsigned int`.

The representation of `unsigned int` might produce unexpected behavior when the values are used as `int` and exceed the range of this type, but for most current architectures it does not pose a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a danger when mixing signed and unsigned versions of the same integer type. Implicit conversions can cause unintentional change of signedness. Calculations can turn up unsigned when you wanted them signed or vice versa. A value which is representable by the unsigned type might not be representable by the signed type. And so on.

As for the specific case of *pointers* to signed/unsigned versions of the *same* type (`int` in this case), there are no additional dangers apart from what is mentioned above. These pointer conversions are considered to be safe, as a special exception in the C standard (1).

So converting between `int*` to/from `unsigned int*` is safe in itself. Please note that this is *not* safe if using two different types though! A conversion from `int*` to `short*` for example, can cause all manner of subtle bugs.

---

(1) In C standard gibberish, C11 6.5/7 ("the strict aliasing rule"):

> "An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of the following types:"
>   ...
>   - "a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object"